# \ifx can't match \read cs

Tags: conditionals

One .dat file contains periods (beginning and ending dates on separate rows) which are to be read once then compared with the date, and if it matches it goes `\immediate\write\fileB{\Date{} #2, #3}` in the command. The MWE given works in the same.

`\read<#> to \whatever` gives ends the cs with a space, which can be gobbled with `\StrGobbleRight{\whatever}{1}[\whatever]` or the definition of `\Date` and be given an extra space at the end, both work outside the command. Inside, however, I can't get it to match and I don't know why, there's obviously something small I'm missing. Both expand to the same thing without any newline, space characters, the `|` in there is just for this. The one conditional is commented out, so I could test the given tex conditionals along with the ones in `xstring`, `etoolbox` has some conditionals, as well, but I've lost tracked of what I've tried already.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{
    etoolbox,
    xstring,
}
\newbool{hasReadPeriod}
\newbool{openDataFile}
\newcounter{foo}


\newcommand\TwoDigits[1]{\ifnum#1<10 0#1\else#1\fi}
\newcounter{year}\setcounter{year}{2016}
\newcounter{month}[year]\setcounter{month}{9}
\newcounter{day}[month]\setcounter{day}{15}
\begin{document}
\newread\fileA
\openin\fileA=periods.dat%

\immediate\newwrite\fileB

\def\Date{\theyear-\TwoDigits{\themonth}-\TwoDigits{\theday}}

\def\XXXX{
    \ifeof\fileA
      % EOF\par
    \else
        \ifbool{hasReadPeriod}%
            {%
                %
            }%
            {%  
                \read\fileA to \aaaaa%
                \StrGobbleRight{\aaaaa}{1}[\aaaaa]%
                \read\fileA to \bbbbb%
                \StrGobbleRight{\bbbbb}{1}[\bbbbb]%
                \global\booltrue{hasReadPeriod}%
            }%
        \ifbool{openDataFile}%
            {%
                \ifx\Date\bbbbb%
                    % OPENDATAFILE
                    \global\boolfalse{openDataFile}%
                    \global\boolfalse{hasReadPeriod}%
                    \immediate\closeout\fileB%
                \else
                    \immediate\write\fileB{\Date{} newstuffhere}%
                \fi
            }%
            {% is closed, should open?
                \ifx\Date\aaaaa %
                    \global\booltrue{openDataFile}%
                    \stepcounter{foo}% `
                    \immediate\openout\fileB=\thefoo.dat%
                    \immediate\write\fileB{\Date newstuffhere}%
                \else
                    \Date|\par%
                    \aaaaa|\par%
                    \hrule\vspace*{0.5cm}%
                \fi

            %   \IfStrEq{\Date{}}{\aaaaa}%
            %       {%
            %           % CLOSEDATAFILE\par%
            %           {\global\booltrue{openDataFile}}%
            %           \stepcounter{foo}%
            %           \immediate\openout\fileB=\thefoo.dat%
            %           \immediate\write\fileB{\Date{} newstuffhere}%
            %       }%
            %       {\Date{}|\par
            %       \aaaaa|\par
            %       \hrule\vspace*{0.5cm}}
            }%
    \fi
    \stepcounter{day}
}
INCREMENT DATE\par
\XXXX{}% 
\XXXX{}%
\XXXX{}%
\XXXX{}%
\XXXX{}%
\XXXX{}%
\XXXX{}%
\XXXX{}%
dasdsad
\def\Date{2016-09-16 }
Date \Date{}\ and \aaaaa{}.
\ifx\Date\aaaaa
    T
\else
    F
\fi

\end{document}
%==========================================
2016-09-16
2016-09-21
```

sample contents of periods.dat

```
2016-09-16
2016-09-21
2016-09-28
2016-09-30
```

Comment: `\ifx\Date{` compares `Date` with `{` which will be false unless `\Date` was defined by `\let\Date{`

Comment: either leave the space there and compare to `\space` or remove it and compare to `\@empty`

Comment: That doesn't explain why they work outside the command, and don't inside. 
I've tried without brackets, 1.dat is always empty. I don't understand why I'd compare it to `\@empty` or `\space`, I'm comparing dates in the form of YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: what works outside the command?  `\ifx\Date{`  compares `\Date` and `{` (so is false) wherever you put it?. I presumed the intention of `\ifx\Date{}` was to test if `\Date` was empty but that should be `\ifx\Date\@empty`

Comment: Added example of it at the end of the doc. Even if defined via the counters and TwoDigits, it works.

Comment: oh but that;s comparng `\Date` and `\aaaa`  which is nothing like you had originally which was comparing `\Date` and `{`  which was why i didn't understand your comment above about it working outside the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\ifx\Date\aaaaa
```

compares `\aaaa` which is defined as if by

```
\def\aaaa{2016-09-15}
```

with `\Date` which is defined by

```
\def\Date{\theyear-\TwoDigits{\themonth}-\TwoDigits{\theday}}
```

as you can see, these are not equal, `\ifx` just compares the list of tokens in the replacement texts of the two macros.  If you had defined `\Date` by

```
 \edef\Date{\theyear-\TwoDigits{\themonth}-\TwoDigits{\theday}}
```

then it would have been defined by the expansion of those tokens at the point of definition so been equivalent to

```
\def\date{2016-09-15}
```

and would then have been `\ifx` equal to `\aaaa`

Comment: This doesn't explain why the `\ifx\Date\aaaaa\` works outside the command environment, as the example at the end shows a 'T'. Changing it to \edef also makes it so it's always the same, that is, you'd have to edef it every time, and even so, it still didn't create a 1.dat - it didn't match, at least on my side ---- "at the point of definition, so jsut stick it in the command, got it. Many thankarinos

Comment: @vlg yes it does because in the example at the end you have defined `\Date` by `\def\Date{2016-09-16 }` so it is `\ifx` equal to `\aaa`  if you have defined it in terms of `\theyear` you would have had to use `\edef` as I explain above.